# C# GetProcesses (Отказано в доступе)

Tags: c#, файлы, процесс

Не могу получить модули приложения. Пишет отказанов в доступе, именно у этого приложения, по видемому там установлены права выше чем у моего приложения, можно ли как установить максимальные права. Сейчас установелны парва администратора через файл манифеста.
Через тот же "Process Hacker" можно посмотреть модули это приложения.

Код получения модулей:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(имя процесса)[0];

        foreach (ProcessModule pm in process.Modules)
            Console.WriteLine(pm.ModuleName);
```

Comment: А запустить от администратора?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Уже сделано, написал же что установлен в файлах манифеста запуск от Имени Администратора

Comment: Установлен - не значит, что запускается от администратора. У вас студия запущена от администратора? В верхнем углу написано "Администратор" ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, всё есть

Comment: Побольше бы конкретики, что за приложение, которое вам отказывается показать модули, и что за задачу вы решаете.

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004513/12888024)

Comment: @aepot Мне нужно узнать все модули прицесса "arma3_x64". Это нужно что бы узнать какие dll используется и сравнивать через некоторое время, что бы узнать нет ли инжектированных dll, а именно читов. Если запускать без 
BattlEye(античит) то всё читается и выводится, а если с ним то пишет "Отказано в доступе". А в том же "Process Hacker" можно всегда увидить все модули а у меня пишет Отказано в доступе

Comment: А вы хотите узнать модули своего приложения или чужого? На свой привелегий не нужно `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules` и поехали. А можно вообще всё адресное пространоство на модули просканировать.